# How to delete a .desktop entry for an app if it remains after uninstallation?

Tags: command-line, software-uninstall

I installed vim editor, but after a day using it I didn't like it, so I used the terminal command `sudo apt remove vim` and the software was uninstalled.

But the icon for `vim` is still there in the [launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ALzd.jpg). When I click it, there are problems.  I'm having the [same issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jaE9.png) with "Netbeans IDE" even though I believe I uninstalled the software properly.

Comment: I don't see an entry for `vim`.  `apt remove` only removes the software but doesn't remove configuration files stored in `~/.config`.  `.desktop` files (application links) are usually in `~/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications/`.  You can generally delete any unused `.desktop` file, but of course make backups in case you make a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

1. sudo apt autoremove vim
2. sudo apt autoremove
3. sudo apt autoclean
   Then do a reboot.